# SQL query to List inactive records plus list last related record

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

SQL Server 2008 R2
I previously posted and received a perfect answer for my issue. But now my client wants to add something else to the query.

I have two tables. I need an inactivity report (which i have been able to create) where the main table has no related records in the notes table for x days.

Now i need to add the date of the last note to this query.

Here is my table structure:

```
Main Table FIELDS > file_number, sysid

Notes Table FIELDS > note_date, main_id
```

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT * 

FROM
  db.main m
  LEFT OUTER JOIN db.notes n
ON m.sysid = n.main_id 
AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD (day, (n.[date]), '1800-12-28'), 101) > dateadd(dd, -14, getdate()) 
WHERE n.main_id is null
```

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: The question is I need to add the last note date as a column. So if the main record has 100 notes and none in the last 14 days (what the above gives me a list of) what was the date of the last note.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    db.main m
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            main_id
            , MAX(n.[DATE]) LastNote
        FROM
            db.notes 
        GROUP BY 
            main_id            
    ) n
    ON 
    n.main_id = m.sysid
WHERE 
    (
        n.main_id IS NULL
        OR 
        DATEDIFF(DAY, n.LastNote getdate()) > 14
    );
```

The main record and the last note date where either the last note is older than 14 days, or a blank lastDate if there are no notes at all.